# copy from postgres table to csv rows splitted

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm making a copy from a postgres table to a csv file.
My command is:

```
copy tableA to 'C:/test/tableA.csv' CSV DELIMITER ','  HEADER ENCODING 'UTF-8'
```

This command worked fine for millions of cases but now I have lines on the csv that are splitting. Probably in postgres records there are extravagant characters but I dont see nothing. Can anybody help me? Thank you

Comment: \copy tableA to '/test/tableA.csv' with delimiter ',' csv header quote as '"'

Comment: thanks but doesnt work

Comment: whats the exact error?..

Comment: one row table is splitted in csv file  in 3 different row as if there are  2 "carriage return"